# Average time on page for a specific sequence of pageviews

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I want to know how long it takes an average user to create an account.
Basically, I have a registration page and a successful registration page after submission.
How can I see the average time on page on the registration page in sessions where the next page is the success page?
Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a segment defining the sequence of the pages. At that point, having in the reports only the data of your interest, you can check in the 'All pages' report the time on the page for the registration page (which will only refer to that page for actually registered users).

Comment: Thanks, Michele.
Great solution.